# How to retrieve the value from nested content inside Umbraco Grid using LeBlender editor

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to retrieve the values from a nested content property editor inside a LeBlender Editor.

This is my current code:

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Lecoati.LeBlender.Extension.Models.LeBlenderModel>

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {       

  var listitems = item.GetValue("checkpointlist"); 

  <p>@listitems</p>

}
```

This outputs:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent]
```

I'm very new to C# and Umbraco, but how do I manage to output the value of the list / my nested content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.GetValue("checkpointlist")` returns a list of IPublishedContent items, you can loop through this with another foreach loop. The example belows outputs the name of the items in the list. If you want to output a specific property, you can replace `.Name` by `.GetPropertyValue("name_of_the_property")`

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Lecoati.LeBlender.Extension.Models.LeBlenderModel>
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{       
    var listitems = item.GetValue<List<IPublishedContent>>("checkpointlist"); 
    foreach (var listitem in listitems)
    {  
        <p>@listitem.Name</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

thanks for your quick reply :)

When I tried this, I got the following error:

CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Could this be related to that the item in the list is nested content? The nested content document type in question only contains a text field named "text".  I tried using @listitem.text or GetValue("text"), but didn't work neither :(

Comment: You'll probably need to use `listitem.GetPropertyValue<string>("text")` to read the text property

Comment: Hm..got a new error now:

"error CS1928: char does not contain a definition for GetPropertyValue and the best extension method overloadmbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.GetPropertyValue<T>(Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent, string) has some invalid arguments."

Comment: I've updated my answer, the `GetValue` of `LeBlenderValue` returns a string value, so you'll have to specify the return type like this: `GetValue<List<IPublishedContent>>`

Comment: It's a LeBlender Editor property:  

Datatype: Checkpoint list - nested content 
Alias: checkpointlist

When I look at the data type "checkpoint list - nested content":

Property editor: Nested content
Property Editor alias: Umbraco.NestedContent
Doc types: (here i selected my nested content document type).

Comment: If I try to use @item.GetRawValue("checkpointlist"); I get the following output:

[ { "key": "484bac31-cccc-41e2-ad0a-be597fabcdb4", "name": "test 1", "ncContentTypeAlias": "sjekkpunktListe", "text": "test 1" }, { "key": "8b375121-bb0c-49ce-acff-0b5a5c75cfe6", "name": "test 2", "ncContentTypeAlias": "sjekkpunktListe", "text": "test 2" }, { "key": "5aff5fcf-4b3b-4146-8b1f-ca1c84d7f490", "name": "test 3", "ncContentTypeAlias": "sjekkpunktListe", "text": "test 3" }, { "key": "2f92607f-a081-491f-a105-e770d7fa82e9", "name": "Item 4", "ncContentTypeAlias": "sjekkpunktListe", "text": "test 4" } ]

Comment: Check out my updated answer, that should return the right type.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)